# How to ignore a servicetype from servicefabric manifest file on build/deploy

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am playing with service fabric and have a package that include two actors and a service and upon build the manifest file of my application is automatically updated to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="MessageProcessor.ServiceFabricHostType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="QueueListenerActorService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="10" />
      <Parameter Name="QueueManagerActorService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="10" />
      <Parameter Name="QueueManagerActorService_MinReplicaSetSize" DefaultValue="2" />
      <Parameter Name="QueueManagerActorService_TargetReplicaSetSize" DefaultValue="3" />
      <Parameter Name="ManagementApiService_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
   </Parameters>
   <ServiceManifestImport>
      <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.2" />
   </ServiceManifestImport>
   <DefaultServices>
      <Service Name="QueueManagerActorService" GeneratedIdRef="1fbd648e-7780-4ddb-869e-9bc965f0d15f">
         <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="QueueManagerActorServiceType" TargetReplicaSetSize="[QueueManagerActorService_TargetReplicaSetSize]" MinReplicaSetSize="[QueueManagerActorService_MinReplicaSetSize]">
            <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[QueueManagerActorService_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
         </StatefulService>
      </Service>
      <Service Name="ManagementApiService">
         <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="ManagementApiServiceType" InstanceCount="[ManagementApiService_InstanceCount]">
            <SingletonPartition />
         </StatelessService>
      </Service>
      <Service Name="QueueListenerActorService" GeneratedIdRef="06c6a81c-fbb7-4938-97b5-15e76888363c">
         <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="QueueListenerActorServiceType">
            <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[QueueListenerActorService_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
         </StatelessService>
      </Service>
   </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

but I would like it not deploy the `QueueListenerActorService` since i will in application code set it up later with some placement constraints that are not known at deploy time.

`

```
    var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
    var services = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(new Uri("fabric:/MessageProcessor.ServiceFabricHost"), new Uri("fabric:/MessageProcessor.ServiceFabricHost/QueueListenerActorService"));
    await fabricClient.ServiceManager.CreateServiceAsync(new StatelessServiceDescription
    {
        ServiceTypeName = "QueueListenerActorServiceType",
        ServiceName = serviceUri,
        PartitionSchemeDescription = new UniformInt64RangePartitionSchemeDescription { PartitionCount = 2, LowKey = Int64.MinValue, HighKey = Int64.MaxValue },
        InstanceCount = 1,
        PlacementConstraints = "NodeType == something",
        ApplicationName = new Uri("fabric:/MessageProcessor.ServiceFabricHost"),
    });
```

If i delete it from manifest file, then it is generated again upon build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out as part of the Actor Nuget packages a build script is included that can generate and update the service and application manifest automaticly using a tool `FabActUtil.exe`.

By changing the project file .csproj of the project containing the actors and setting property.

```
<UpdateServiceFabricManifestEnabled>false</UpdateServiceFabricManifestEnabled>
```

the tool can be disabled.

and then I could comment out the service i wanted to ignore.

## Update using grunt

So since grunt almost is a first hand citizen in visual studio i decided to use it for automating this. The problem of disabling the above property is that its annoying to unload the project to  enable it to generate new manifest when new actors are added. Now I have a grunt task that makes it much easier.

#### gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-xmlstoke');

    grunt.registerTask("FabActUtil", ["copy:FabActUtilBackup", "copy:FabActUtil", "exec:FabActUtil","xmlstoke:FabActUtil","clean:FabActUtil"]);

    var relativePackageDir = "../../packages/";
    var buildDir = "bin/x64/Debug/";
    var temp = "artifacts"
    var assemblyName = "S-Innovations.Azure.MessageProcessor.ServiceFabric.exe";
    var relativeAppDir = "../MessageProcessor.ServiceFabricHost/";
    var appManifest = relativeAppDir + 'ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml';

    grunt.initConfig({
        copy:{
            FabActUtil:{
                src: relativePackageDir + "Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors*/build/FabActUtil.exe",
                dest: buildDir+"FabActUtil.exe"
            },
            FabActUtilBackup:{
                src:appManifest,
                dest: appManifest+".bac"
            }
        },
        clean:{
            FabActUtil: ["bin/x64/Debug/FabActUtil.exe"],
        },
        exec: {
            // Run tsd link to add bower/npm packages typescript definition files.
            "FabActUtil": {
                cmd: 'bin\\x64\\Debug\\FabActUtil.exe /app:' + relativeAppDir.replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'), "\\") + '\\ApplicationPackageRoot /out:' + temp.replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'), "\\") + ' /spp:PackageRoot /in:' +buildDir.replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'),"\\")+ assemblyName,
            }
        },
        xmlstoke: {
            FabActUtil: {
                options: {
                    actions: [{
                        xpath: '//DefaultServices/Service[@Name="QueueListenerActorService"]',
                        type: 'D'
                    }],
                },
                files: { appManifest: appManifest },
            },
        },
    })
}
```

with the following packages installed automatically in vs when adding package.json

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "sf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": { },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-xmlstoke": "0.7.1"
  }
}
```

Note that to use this one have to fix the paths.